# How connect to MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql, database

How connect to MySQL?(C#)

**Server:**

Localhost via UNIX socket

**My code:**

```
public void Connect()
{
    server = "91.196.48.243";
    database = "w554_users";
    port = "3306";
    uid = "name";
    password = "password";

    myConnectionString = "Server=" + server + ";" + "Port=" + port + ";" + "Database=" +
    database + ";" + "Uid=" + uid + ";" + "Pwd=" + password + ";";
    conn = new MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);

    conn.Open();
}
```

**And give me this error:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Host '188.47.8.212' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server

=========================================================================

If I log on phpmyadmin

[Ip: 91.196.48.243](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9ywY.jpg)

=================

I changed port(2222)

**Error:**

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TimeoutException' occurred in MySql.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Timeout in IO operation

Comment: in mysql you need to allow access to this specific ip , username and password to remotely access the db

Comment: this is a namedpipes / ip issue ping sounds like you need to make sure you have the database configured to access based on ipaddress also can you ping that server from your current location.. I would also look into using a .config file to setup your db connection etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your IP doesnt have permission to access mysql sever.

> Additional information: Host '188.47.8.212' is not allowed to connect
>   to this MySQL server

Try this solution in your DrirectAdmin:

> If you have a MySQL database with your hosting account and need to
>   connect to it from your home computer, or another web server, you'll
>   need to add a remote "Access Host" to your database to allow the
>   connection in. Go to:
>
> ```
> User Level -> MySQL Management -> databasename -> Add Access Host
> ```
>
> You can either add the IP of the remote connecting box, or just use: `%`
>
> to allow any IP (if you're unsure of the remote IP, or if it may
>   change)
>
> Note that the correct login/password is still required, the Access
>   Host is just another layer of security.
>
> Also make sure that port 3306 is open in your firewall on the
>   DirectAdmin box, so the remote box can connect.

[Connect to your MySQL database from a remote connection](https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=308)

Answer (score 0):

Your MYSQL server doesnt allow incoming connections from that IP, be sure to allow it from the Server's end.